# Baffled by SoapFaultClientException using Spring WS, HttpClient, and Exchange WS

Tags: java, httpclient, spring-ws, exchangewebservices

I am attempting to call the Exchange WS 2010 API with Spring WS + HttpClient.  I get the following error...

```
Jun/27 11:39:06,825 controller.AjaxCalendarController.[] - Unknown Error
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: The request is invalid.
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:37)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:774)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:600)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:384)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378)
    at org.jasig.portlet.calendar.adapter.ExchangeCalendarAdapter.retrieveExchangeEvents(ExchangeCalendarAdapter.java:171)
    at org.jasig.portlet.calendar.adapter.ExchangeCalendarAdapter.getEvents(ExchangeCalendarAdapter.java:132)
    at org.jasig.portlet.calendar.adapter.CalendarEventsDao.getEvents(CalendarEventsDao.java:74)
    at org.jasig.portlet.calendar.mvc.controller.AjaxCalendarController.getEventList(AjaxCalendarController.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:345)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleResource(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doResourceService(DispatcherPortlet.java:825)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:525)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.serveResource(FrameworkPortlet.java:477)
    at org.jasig.portal.portlet.container.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:212)
    at org.jasig.portal.portlet.container.FilterChainImpl.processFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:84)
    at org.jasig.portal.portlet.container.FilterManagerImpl.processFilter(FilterManagerImpl.java:103)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:350)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet.doGet(PortletServlet.java:261)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.container.DefaultPortletInvokerService.invoke(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:229)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.container.DefaultPortletInvokerService.serveResource(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at org.jasig.portal.portlet.dao.jpa.ThreadContextClassLoaderAspect.doThreadContextClassLoaderUpdate(ThreadContextClassLoaderAspect.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy210.serveResource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.impl.PortletContainerImpl.doServeResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:203)
    at org.jasig.portal.portlet.rendering.PortletRendererImpl.doServeResource(PortletRendererImpl.java:598)
    at org.jasig.portal.portlet.rendering.worker.PortletResourceExecutionWorker.callInternal(PortletResourceExecutionWorker.java:54)
    at org.jasig.portal.portlet.rendering.worker.PortletResourceExecutionWorker.callInternal(PortletResourceExecutionWorker.java:32)
    at org.jasig.portal.portlet.rendering.worker.PortletExecutionWorker$1.call(PortletExecutionWorker.java:165)
    at org.jasig.portal.portlet.rendering.worker.PortletExecutionCallable.call(PortletExecutionCallable.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

It doesn't tell me anything about what it thinks is wrong with the request.  :(  On the server-side, both IIS and Exchange merely state that a request came through from me and an HTTP 500 was returned.

Here's is the SOAP envelope (captured from the logs):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:GetUserAvailabilityRequest xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <ns3:TimeZone>
                <ns3:Bias>0</ns3:Bias>
                <ns3:StandardTime>
                    <ns3:Bias>0</ns3:Bias>
                    <ns3:Time>02:00:00</ns3:Time>
                    <ns3:DayOrder>1</ns3:DayOrder>
                    <ns3:Month>11</ns3:Month>
                    <ns3:DayOfWeek>Sunday</ns3:DayOfWeek>
                </ns3:StandardTime>
                <ns3:DaylightTime>
                    <ns3:Bias>0</ns3:Bias>
                    <ns3:Time>02:00:00</ns3:Time>
                    <ns3:DayOrder>1</ns3:DayOrder>
                    <ns3:Month>3</ns3:Month>
                    <ns3:DayOfWeek>Sunday</ns3:DayOfWeek>
                </ns3:DaylightTime>
            </ns3:TimeZone>
            <ns2:MailboxDataArray>
                <ns3:MailboxData>
                    <ns3:Email>
                        <ns3:Name>Drew Wills</ns3:Name>
                        <ns3:Address>unicon@stcloudstate.edu</ns3:Address>
                    </ns3:Email>
                    <ns3:AttendeeType>Required</ns3:AttendeeType>
                    <ns3:ExcludeConflicts>false</ns3:ExcludeConflicts>
                </ns3:MailboxData>
            </ns2:MailboxDataArray>
            <ns3:FreeBusyViewOptions>
                <ns3:TimeWindow>
                    <ns3:StartTime>2012-06-27T00:00:00.000</ns3:StartTime>
                    <ns3:EndTime>2012-07-04T00:00:00.000</ns3:EndTime>
                </ns3:TimeWindow>
                <ns3:MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes>60</ns3:MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes>
                <ns3:RequestedView>DetailedMerged</ns3:RequestedView>
            </ns3:FreeBusyViewOptions>
        </ns2:GetUserAvailabilityRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here also is some trace logging that shows HTTP headers and so forth...

```
Jun/27 11:39:06,773 conn.DefaultClientConnection.[] - Sending request: POST /EWS/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Jun/27 11:39:06,773 http.wire.[] - >> "POST /EWS/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,773 http.wire.[] - >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,773 http.wire.[] - >> "Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,773 http.wire.[] - >> "SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/GetUserAvailability"[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,773 http.wire.[] - >> "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,773 http.wire.[] - >> "Content-Length: 1362[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,773 http.wire.[] - >> "Host: mail.stcloudstate.edu[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.wire.[] - >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.wire.[] - >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.wire.[] - >> "Cookie: exchangecookie=49398e25ac5b4b84a19f93d170b3eefa[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.wire.[] - >> "Cookie2: $Version=1[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.wire.[] - >> "Authorization: NTLM xxx[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.wire.[] - >> "[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.headers.[] - >> POST /EWS/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.headers.[] - >> Accept-Encoding: gzip
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.headers.[] - >> Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.headers.[] - >> SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/GetUserAvailability"
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.headers.[] - >> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.headers.[] - >> Content-Length: 1362
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.headers.[] - >> Host: mail.stcloudstate.edu
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.headers.[] - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.headers.[] - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Jun/27 11:39:06,774 http.headers.[] - >> Cookie: exchangecookie=49398e25ac5b4b84a19f93d170b3eefa
Jun/27 11:39:06,775 http.headers.[] - >> Cookie2: $Version=1
Jun/27 11:39:06,775 http.headers.[] - >> Authorization: NTLM xxx
Jun/27 11:39:06,776 http.wire.[] - >> "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:GetUserAvailabilityRequest xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><ns3:TimeZone><ns3:Bias>0</ns3:Bias><ns3:StandardTime><ns3:Bias>0</ns3:Bias><ns3:Time>02:00:00</ns3:Time><ns3:DayOrder>1</ns3:DayOrder><ns3:Month>11</ns3:Month><ns3:DayOfWeek>Sunday</ns3:DayOfWeek></ns3:StandardTime><ns3:DaylightTime><ns3:Bias>0</ns3:Bias><ns3:Time>02:00:00</ns3:Time><ns3:DayOrder>1</ns3:DayOrder><ns3:Month>3</ns3:Month><ns3:DayOfWeek>Sunday</ns3:DayOfWeek></ns3:DaylightTime></ns3:TimeZone><ns2:MailboxDataArray><ns3:MailboxData><ns3:Email><ns3:Name>Drew Wills</ns3:Name><ns3:Address>unicon@stcloudstate.edu</ns3:Address></ns3:Email><ns3:AttendeeType>Required</ns3:AttendeeType><ns3:ExcludeConflicts>false</ns3:ExcludeConflicts></ns3:MailboxData></ns2:MailboxDataArray><ns3:FreeBusyViewOptions><ns3:TimeWindow><ns3:StartTime>2012-06-27T00:00:00.000</ns3:StartTime><ns3:EndTime>2012-07-04T00:00:00.000</ns3:EndTime></ns3:TimeWindow><ns3:MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes>60</ns3:MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes><ns3:RequestedView>DetailedMerged</ns3:RequestedView></ns3:FreeBusyViewOptions></ns2:GetUserAvailabilityRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
Jun/27 11:39:06,801 http.wire.[] - << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,801 http.wire.[] - << "Cache-Control: private[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,801 http.wire.[] - << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,801 http.wire.[] - << "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.wire.[] - << "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.wire.[] - << "X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.wire.[] - << "Persistent-Auth: true[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.wire.[] - << "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.wire.[] - << "Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2012 18:39:05 GMT[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.wire.[] - << "[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 conn.DefaultClientConnection.[] - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.headers.[] - << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.headers.[] - << Cache-Control: private
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.headers.[] - << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.headers.[] - << Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.headers.[] - << Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.headers.[] - << X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.headers.[] - << Persistent-Auth: true
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.headers.[] - << X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Jun/27 11:39:06,802 http.headers.[] - << Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2012 18:39:05 GMT
Jun/27 11:39:06,804 exchange.NtlmAuthHttpClient.[] - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Jun/27 11:39:06,808 http.wire.[] - << "247[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,808 http.wire.[] - << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorInvalidRequest</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The request is invalid.</faultstring><detail><e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorInvalidRequest</e:ResponseCode><e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request is invalid.</e:Message></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>"
Jun/27 11:39:06,808 http.wire.[] - << "[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,808 http.wire.[] - << "0[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,808 http.wire.[] - << "[\r][\n]"
Jun/27 11:39:06,809 tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.[] - Released connection is reusable.
```

Thank you mightily for any assistance with this thorny issue.

Comment: can you paste the wsdl ?

Comment: @Gergely It's huge... looking for a link I can post to it.  In the mean time, here's a navigable reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563800(v=exchg.140).aspx  It has an example envelope (doesn't look different from mine to me).

Comment: Strange. No soap-headers in the example either. You did try to consume this service with soapUI, didn't you?

Comment: @GergelySzilagyi -- just tried it, but apparently... "soapUI currently does not support NTLMv2, so if your server requires this you will either need to reconfigure the server to accept NTLMv1 (see...) or use a product like (...) to overcome this."

Comment: Came across the same thing, nevertheless I've found soapUI a must have and here's why: WSDL is a contract, right? Most frameworks will adhere to that, but soapUI really tries its best to generate _correct_ requests. Even if I don't send them, it helps me find out what I'm missing in my client. And when I develop services, the builtin WSI conformance check saved my life a few times :) glad you could use soapUI to track down the problem. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working -- here are the details...

I used SoapUI to gain some insights..  I wanted to test my SOAP envelope (generated by my code) but... "soapUI currently does not support NTLMv2, so if your server requires this you will either need to reconfigure the server to accept NTLMv1 (see...) or use a product like (...) to overcome this."

I wasn't much surprised.  NTLM AuthN was the nightmare of the previous 2 days, and it's a monster to get working in Java.  [This article](http://www.vodori.com/blog/ntlmv2-authentication-from-java-a-developers-odyssey.html) helped immesely, but in my case I also had to force my code to send NTLM creds for the "negotiate" (SPNEGO) scheme.  (It would choose kerberos, but give up because it didn't have kerberos creds... argh!)

SoapUI also could generate a sample request, which I reviewed.  It looked quite a bit like mine, but had additionally a few optional (seemingly) bits.  Most were optional, but apparently one isn't.

The web service wanted this soap header:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header><ns3:RequestServerVersion xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="Exchange2010_SP2"/></SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

The MSDN API documentation *says* the soap header is optional, but it started working when I sent it.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. How did you add the custom soap header (RequestServerVersion) using Spring WS client?

Answer (score 2):

So if you take the client out of the picture, and simply mimic the request using curl, can you  verify that you still get a 500 response?

That would at least isolate the problem to the server side.

You might be able to more easily debug the issue using curl by playing around with HTTP header values or the contents of the soap entity.

Comment: It's a good suggestion.  I ended up trying with SoapUI (I'm on windows), but it couldn't get passed the NTLM authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I have been experiencing the same issue -- the EWS service for a local Exchange 2010 install rejects requests that include an empty "soap-env:header" element. I verified the issue using cURL with the following SOAP XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:GetFolder xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
                   xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <ns2:FolderShape>
            <ns3:BaseShape>Default</ns3:BaseShape>
        </ns2:FolderShape>
        <ns2:FolderIds>
            <ns3:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/>
        </ns2:FolderIds>
    </ns2:GetFolder>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Oddly, I could get the EWS service to accept the request by making *any* of the following changes to the "SOAP-ENV:Header" element in the request:

1. Add RequestServerVersion to header as described above
2. Remove the "SOAP-ENV:Header" element entirely
3. Replace the single-tag empty element with a "double-tag" empty element:

Seems to me like a bug in Exchange 2010 EWS.